# Tiered shipping problem in Satchmo

Tags: django, satchmo

When I try to use the tiered shipping module in my store, I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /shop/checkout/dummy/

object.__init__() takes no parameters

Request Method:         GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/checkout/dummy/
Exception Type:         TypeError
Exception Value:

object.__init__() takes no parameters

Exception Location:     ../../apps/shipping/modules/tiered/models.py in __init__, line 28

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
 92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
 44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "../../apps/payment/modules/dummy/views.py" in pay_ship_info
 10.     return payship.credit_pay_ship_info(request, dummy)
File "../../apps/payment/views/payship.py" in credit_pay_ship_info
 141.     return base_pay_ship_info(request, payment_module, credit_pay_ship_process_form, template)
File "../../apps/payment/views/payship.py" in base_pay_ship_info
 132.     results = form_handler(request, contact, working_cart, payment_module)
File "../../apps/payment/views/payship.py" in credit_pay_ship_process_form
 79.         form = _get_form(request, payment_module, *args, **kwargs)
File "../../apps/payment/views/payship.py" in _get_form
 65.         form = formclass(request, payment_module, *args, **kwargs)
File "../../apps/payment/forms.py" in __init__
 226.         super(CreditPayShipForm, self).__init__(request, paymentmodule, *args, **kwargs)
File "../../apps/payment/forms.py" in __init__
 178.         shipping_choices, shipping_dict = _get_shipping_choices(request, paymentmodule, self.tempCart, self.tempContact, default_view_tax=default_view_tax)
File "../../apps/payment/forms.py" in _get_shipping_choices
 40.         methods = shipping_methods()
File "../../apps/shipping/config.py" in shipping_methods
 49.         methods.extend(module.get_methods())
File "../../apps/shipping/modules/tiered/__init__.py" in get_methods
 7.     return [Shipper(carrier) for carrier in Carrier.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('ordering')]
File "../../apps/shipping/modules/tiered/models.py" in __init__
 28.         super(BaseShipper, self).__init__(self)

Exception Type: TypeError at /shop/checkout/dummy/
Exception Value: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

I have entered the carriers in database as well.

Can anyone help me in this regard ?

Answer (score 1):

```
super(BaseShipper, self).__init__(self)
```

change it to

```
super(BaseShipper, self).__init__()
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks to me like a bug and is present in Satchmo trunk.

Change line 28 in satchmo/apps/shipping/modules/tiered/models.py to:

```
super(BaseShipper, self).__init__()
```

and re-run.